# How do I add multiple Groovy map entries without overwriting the current entries?

Tags: dictionary, groovy

My question with Groovy Maps.  I've been searching for a way to programmatically add a new entry to a Groovy map without overwriting the current entry.  For example

```
def editsMap = [:]

lineEdits.flag.each 
{ lineEdits_Flag ->
   editsMap.put('FlagId',lineEdits_Flag.id)
   editsMap.put('FlagMnemonic',lineEdits_Flag.mnemonic)
   editsMap.put('Action',lineEdits_Flag.action)   
   println "editsMap: ${editsMap}"
}
```

The first pass produces this map:
    editsMap: [FlagId:10001, FlagMnemonic:TRA, Action:review]

But the second pass overwrites the first pass with:
    editsMap: [FlagId:10002, FlagMnemonic:REB, Action:deny]

What I'm trying to do is create multiple entries within the one map.  I need my map to populate something like this:

```
editsMap: [FlagId:10001, FlagMnemonic:TRA, Action:review]
editsMap: [FlagId:10002, FlagMnemonic:REB, Action:deny]
editsMap: [FlagId:10003, FlagMnemonic:UNB, Action:deny]
editsMap: [FlagId:20001, FlagMnemonic:REB, Action:deny]
editsMap: [FlagId:20002, FlagMnemonic:ICD, Action:review]
editsMap: [FlagId:30001, FlagMnemonic:REB, Action:deny]
editsMap: [FlagId:40001, FlagMnemonic:ICD, Action:review]
editsMap: [FlagId:40002, FlagMnemonic:MPR, Action:review]
editsMap: [FlagId:50001, FlagMnemonic:CPT, Action:deny]
editsMap: [FlagId:60001, FlagMnemonic:DTU, Action:deny]
editsMap: [FlagId:70001, FlagMnemonic:ICD, Action:review]
editsMap: [FlagId:70002, FlagMnemonic:MPR, Action:review]
```

Once I have populated my map then I need to be able to find certain values in order to process a message.  I believe that I can use something like:

```
def thisValue = appliedEditsMap[FlagId, '10001'] ?: "default"
```

to do a quick lookup.

Can someone help me understand how to programmatically add values to a Groovy map without overwriting the values already in the map?

Answer (score 14):

You want something like [Guava's MultiMap](http://tomjefferys.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/multimaps-google-guava.html):

```
Multimap<String, String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

// Adding some key/value
myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Bannana");
myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Apple");
myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Pear");
myMultimap.put("Vegetables", "Carrot");

// Getting values
Collection<string> fruits = myMultimap.get("Fruits");
System.out.println(fruits); // [Bannana, Apple, Pear]
```

[This guy](http://www.kellyrob99.com/blog/2010/05/15/achieving-groovy-like-fluency-in-java-with-google-collections/) makes a pure Groovy emulation of Multimap:

```
class GroovyMultimap {
    Map map = [:]

    public boolean put(Object key, Object value) {
        List list = map.get(key, [])
        list.add(value)
        map."$key" = list
    }
}
```

You can use `putAt` and `getAt` for syntatic sugar in map operations. You can also try a [mixin](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2013/02/groovy-goodness-apply-mixin-to-object.html) in a map object.

He also uses Groovy with Guava's multimap:

```
List properties = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
Multimap multimap = list.inject(LinkedListMultimap.create()) {
    Multimap map, object ->
    properties.each {
        map.put(it, object."$it")
    }
    map
}
properties.each {
    assertEquals (multimap.get(it), list."$it")
}
```

Comment: You can also do: `[:].withDefault { [] }.with { map -> map.fruit << 'banana' ; map.fruit << 'apple' ; map.veg << 'carrot' ; map }`

Answer (score 9):

I came across this several years ago as an answer to a similar question on another site. I can't find where it originally came from so if anyone knows the source please post it here.

```
LinkedHashMap.metaClass.multiPut << { key, value ->
    delegate[key] = delegate[key] ?: []; delegate[key] += value
}

def myMap = [:]

myMap.multiPut("a", "1")
myMap.multiPut("a", "2")
myMap.multiPut("a", "3")

myMap.each {key, list ->
    println '${key} -> ${list}'
}
```

Gives:

```
a -> 1,2,3
```

The use of the injected **multiPut()** method does the magic.

Comment: when I use this logic in jenkins, I get 
`hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.multiPut() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [a, 1]
Possible solutions: multiPut(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)` Any idea why?

Comment: @user2700022 Not specifically no. It been a long time since I did much groovy or Jenkins. In a Jenkinsfile, you may have an object you _think_ is a string, but isn't actually a string, particularly if it's an object coming from the Jenkins environment.
You could try explicit type hints for the multiPut method - again, it's been many years since I did any Groovy so I'm not sure if that would work

Answer (score 6):

You could also do something like this:

```
// Dummy map for testing
lineEdits = [ flag:[
  [id:10001, mnemonic:'TRA', action:'review'],
  [id:10002, mnemonic:'REB', action:'deny'],
  [id:10003, mnemonic:'UNB', action:'deny'],
  [id:20001, mnemonic:'REB', action:'deny'],
  [id:20002, mnemonic:'ICD', action:'review'],
  [id:30001, mnemonic:'REB', action:'deny'],
  [id:40001, mnemonic:'ICD', action:'review'],
  [id:40002, mnemonic:'MPR', action:'review'],
  [id:50001, mnemonic:'CPT', action:'deny'],
  [id:60001, mnemonic:'DTU', action:'deny'],
  [id:70001, mnemonic:'ICD', action:'review'],
  [id:70002, mnemonic:'MPR', action:'review'] ] ]

def editsMap = lineEdits.flag
                        .groupBy { it.id } // Group by id
                        .collectEntries { k, v ->
                          [ k, v[ 0 ] ] // Just grab the first one (flatten)
                        }

assert editsMap[ 60001 ] == [ id:60001, mnemonic:'DTU', action:'deny' ]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do the multimap thing without external classes, you can just store a map of lists instead, the syntax won't be cumbersome or anything.

```
def editsMap = [:].withDefault{[]}
lineEdits.flag.each 
{ 
   lineEdits_Flag ->
   editsMap.FlagId << lineEdits_Flag.id
   editsMap.FlagMnemonic << lineEdits_Flag.mnemonic
   editsMap.Action << lineEdits_Flag.action
   println "editsMap: ${editsMap}"
}
```

or if you really preferred your original syntax it would look like:

`editsMap.get('FlagId').add(lineEdits_Flag.id)`

or even this should work:

`editsMap.get('FlagId') << lineEdits_Flag.id`

The advantage of this solution is that it tends to be more obvious what you are doing... for instance it's not a magic map that converts single items to a list (which is not the standard map contract) but it's always a map of lists that you simply use as a map of lists.

The .get will always work the same way the multimap was described--it will always return the list for that item in the map.

Answer (score 2):

A map is a set of key-value mappings, you plug in different values by key so that you can use the key to find them later. Your example is plugging in values for the same keys over and over. You need to pick unique keys.

Make some class to store your values for one entry in the map:

```
class Stuff {
    String flagMnemonic
    String action
}
```

Make a map where you will use flagId as the key (because that's how you identify the flag uniquely) and Stuff as the value (because it's the data you want to lookup).

```
def editsMap = [:]
```

If you used type declarations here, and if flagId is a String, the map's type would be `Map<String, Stuff>`.

Now you can put stuff in the map:

```
lineEdits.flag.each { lineEdits_Flag -> 
    editsMap[lineEdits_Flag.id] = 
    new Stuff(
        flagMnemonic: lineEdits_Flag.mnemonic, 
        action: lineEdits_Flag.action) 
}
```

and get it back out with

```
def myStuffFor10001 = editsMap['10001']
println myStuffFor10001.flagMnemonic // should equal 'TRA'
println myStuffFor10001.action // should equal 'review'
```

Also there's an easy alternative to using `?: "default"` to set default values, you can use `withDefault` when creating your map:

```
def defaultStuff = new Stuff(
    flagMnemonic: "defaultMnemonic", action:"defaultAction")
def editsMap = [:].withDefault { defaultStuff }
```

so that whenever you ask for something from the map that is not present there, you get the specified default object.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a list and closure like:

```
editsList = [
[FlagId:10001, FlagMnemonic:TRA, Action:review],
[FlagId:10002, FlagMnemonic:REB, Action:deny],
[FlagId:10003, FlagMnemonic:UNB, Action:deny],
[FlagId:20001, FlagMnemonic:REB, Action:deny],
[FlagId:20002, FlagMnemonic:ICD, Action:review],
[FlagId:30001, FlagMnemonic:REB, Action:deny],
[FlagId:40001, FlagMnemonic:ICD, Action:review], 
[FlagId:40002, FlagMnemonic:MPR, Action:review],
[FlagId:50001, FlagMnemonic:CPT, Action:deny],
[FlagId:60001, FlagMnemonic:DTU, Action:deny],
[FlagId:70001, FlagMnemonic:ICD, Action:review],
[FlagId:70002, FlagMnemonic:MPR, Action:review]
]
def appliedEditsMap = {property,idValue->
     return editsList.find{it[property] == idValue}
}
def thisValue = appliedEditsMap(FlagId, '10001') ?: "default"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this in to a class and then add that class in to the Map. From what I see your information is related so having a class to store makes sense unless I'm missing anything

What you can do is define your class as

```
class Flag {

String flagID
String flagMnemonic
String action
}

Now Put your Flag in to your map as

editsMap.put(10000,newFlag(flagID:'10000',flagMnemonic:'TES',action:'tes'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently and I knew it was possible because some coworkers had done it. Reading the answers here and experimenting, I finally found a simple answer that worked for my use-case and isn't difficult to read. Writing a "generic code" answer makes this a little less readable than it is in our code with the proper column names, etc...

In my case, I was getting a `List<Map>` back from a repo query; I needed something like `Map<String, List<Object>>` and I need to add to the `List` if a result set's key matched a previous one. Of course, my `Object` wasn't a POJO, but you can use any Class. And to further complicate it, I needed to create a composite key from a few of the result values (don't ask, I didn't create it) *and* remove those keys from the original Map so I could use the remaining entries to create a business Object.

Here's what I did:

```
List<Map> listMap = repo.findWhateverItWas()

Map<String, List<Object>> resultMap = [:].withDefault {[]}  //required to avoid NPE

listMap.each { Map<String, Object> it ->
    String compKey = it['col1'] + it['col2'] + it['col3']

    Map tempMap =[:]
    it.keySet.each { k ->
        if (!(k in ['col1','col2','col3'])) {
            tempMap << [(k): it[k]]        // this is the business Object result map
        }
    }

    // createEntity is a static Entity Factory
    // the simple += is the magic
    resultMap[(compKey)] += createEntity(Entity.class, tempMap)

}

return resultMap
```

I realize this doesn't address your specific scenario, but I do believe it answers the question and provides an answer for a more complex situation.

I was able to prove the expected functionality of this with a simple test case. We use Spock...

```
def "Map of Lists test"() {
    given:
        Map<String, List<String>> map = [:].withDefault { [] }
    when:
        map['key1'] += 'item1'
        map['key1'] += 'item2'
        map['key2'] += 'item3'
        map['key1'] += 'item4'
        map['key2'] += 'item5'
    then:
        map['key1'] == ['item1', 'item2', 'item4']
        map['key2'] == ['item3', 'item5']
}
```