# Put to map if absent in Groovy without Java 8

Tags: dictionary, groovy

I need to put an entries to the map only if the keys are not present yet. With Java 8 I'd just use `putIfAbsent`, but I'm using Groovy with Java 7.

Code illustrating the problem:

```
def map = [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]
def newEntries = [a: 11, b: 22, d: 44]

def result = // put new entries to the map only if they are not present

assert result == [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 44]
```

Is it possible to use some Groovy feature to do that or do I need to do it manually?

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640525/how-do-i-add-multiple-groovy-map-entries-without-overwriting-the-current-entries ?

Comment: No, I don't need `Multimap`, just `HashMap` is fine for my problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just figured out that this works as well:

```
def map = [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]
def newEntries = [a: 11, b: 22, d: 44]

def result = newEntries + map

assert result == [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 44]
```

It's enough to override default entries with original ones.

Answer (score 3):

You could roll your own with meta-programming:

```
Map.metaClass.putIfAbsent = { otherMap ->
    otherMap.each { k, v ->
        if (! delegate.keySet().contains(k)) {
            delegate.put(k, v)
        }
    }
    delegate
}

def map = [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]
def newEntries = [a: 11, b: 22, d: 44]

def result = map.putIfAbsent(newEntries)

assert [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 44] == result
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Michael Easter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12704/michael-easter)'s solution is quite elegant, but you could also just use [java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) which was introduced in Java 1.5, and provides the [putIfAbsent(K key, V value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent(K,%20V)) method. As such, you can implement your code as:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
def map = new ConcurrentHashMap([a: 1, b: 2, c: 3])

[a: 11, b: 22, d: 44].each() { k,v ->
    map.putIfAbsent(k,v);
}

assert [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 44] == map;
```

Comment: Yep, nice - however `ConcurrentHashMap` creates a lot of `ConcurrentHashMap$Segment`, `ConcurrentHashMap$HashEntry[]` and `ReentrantLock$NonfairSync` in memory and for such simple operation it looks like overkill :)

Answer (score 1):

There is also Groovy's `Map.withDefault()` method, which is a good deal more flexible but can be used for this purpose. The behavior would be somewhat different, since the default values are not actually *added* to the map until they are first requested:

```
def map = [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]
def newEntries = [a: 11, b: 22, d: 44]

def result = map.withDefault { k -> newEntries[k] }

assert result == map
assert result != [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 44]
assert newEntries.keySet().every { k -> result[k] == map[k] ?: newEntries[k] }
assert result == [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 44]
```