# What does colon enclosed by square brackets [:] mean in Java/groovy?

Tags: groovy

While reading a nextflow pipeline, i encountered such notation:

`channel = [:]`

Which is later used in such manner:

```
anotherChannel.each { integer, file ->

  if ( !channel.containsKey(integer) ) {
   channel.put(integer, [])
  }
  channel.get(integer).add(file)

}
```

**Is it some special list notation?** The reason i need to understand it is i have to add another file to it, something like this:

```
anotherChannel.each { integer, file, file2 ->

  if ( !channel.containsKey(integer) ) {
   channel.put(integer, [])
  }
  channel.get(integer).add(file, file2)

}
```

But it obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \[:\] mean in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865107/what-does-mean-in-groovy)

Comment: Yes! If you find it easy to iterate on the second part of my q, would be greateful short term.

Comment: see something like this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15641606/9808792) then. You can't add multiple keys to a value in a generic map (since maps map a unique key to ONE value).

Comment: Why tagged "java" when it's about groovy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the second part of your question, the following creates a closure with 2 arguments and passes it as an argument to `Map.each`

```
anotherChannel.each { integer, file ->    
}
```

This closure will be called once for each entry in `anotherChannel` with the entry's key assigned to `integer` and the entry's value assigned to `file`. You can't just add another argument to this closure, because [`Map.each`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#each(groovy.lang.Closure)) doesn't support a 3-argument closure.

I think this will do what you want

```
anotherChannel.each { integer, file ->

  def files = channel.putIfAbsent(integer, [])
  files.addAll([file1, file2])
}
```

Comment: Your solution seems perfect (simple), but i do get an error: _Invalid method `doCall` invocation with arguments: [integer, file1, file2] (java.util.ArrayList) on _runScript_closure8 type_

Comment: I came up with a solution to simply define a second channel!

Answer (score 0):

`[:]` creates an empty map while `[]` creates an empty list.